# Emmet tab autocomplete not functioning in Brackets 0.42

Tags: emmet, adobe-brackets

When trying to use Emmet to do any style settings in an html file, instead of using the autocomplete, it creates a new tab, e.g., if I have the following

```
<div>
```

and I want to add a margin of 10px, I add

```
<div style="m10
```

then press tab and instead of

```
<div style="margin:10px;">
```

I get

```
<div style="<m10></m10>"
```

Most of the other Emmet functions, creating lists, div with class, work fine. I'm using Brackets 0.42 and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Emmet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Cheat Sheet [**here**](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) you can't do that. 
The html file only parse emmet magic code like ul>li*4.. or building tags like div [TAB] -> `<div></div>`

In css as you know you can use m10 [TAB] to get `margin: 10px;`.

*(Styling inline in html isn't a good approach if you can avoid it)*

**EDIT**: What you can actually do to keep your workflow is:

1. type div [TAB] -> `<div></div>`
2. click in the open or closing div
3. press CTRL+E (Quick Edit) and define a new style in your css file for this specific div. Emmet works in the Quick Edit window as intended.

This is the best valid way.